# How to center my Playgrounds Live View

Tags: xcode, swift-playground, liveview

I am instantiating a playground live view using the following code:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

let view = UIView()
view.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 100)
view.backgroundColor = .white


PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = view
```

The live view that appears is stuck to the top of the screen and I can't change it's location by changing the x and y values of the frame. How do I get the view to move/center on my screen?

Photo of how it comes out:

[image: Xcode Live View]

Comment: You could just enclose it to a (larger) superview. Why do you need this btw?